# eje secundario ggplot (sec.axis) con geom_bar()

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Tengo una función que añade un eje vertical secundario a un gráfico, para representar una segunda variable sobre el mismo eje horizontal.

El código es el siguiente:

```
gplot2eix <- function(data, x, y1, y2, geom, colour= "steelblue", alpha= 1, facDM= NULL){

  library(ggplot2)

  x <- deparse(substitute(x))
  y1 <- deparse(substitute(y1))
  y2 <- deparse(substitute(y2))

  maxAxiY1 <- max(data[[y1]], na.rm= T)
  maxAxiY2 <- max(data[[y2]], na.rm= T)
  minAxiY1 <- min(data[[y1]], na.rm= T)
  minAxiY2 <- min(data[[y2]], na.rm= T)

  offSet <- maxAxiY1-maxAxiY2

  #El factor divisor/multiplicador de escala para el eje secundario, se puede introducir manualmente, y si no se calcula solo

  if(is.null(facDM)){
  facDM = ((maxAxiY1 - minAxiY1)/(maxAxiY2 - minAxiY2))
  }

  print(facDM)

  vecLim <- c(min(maxAxiY1, maxAxiY2*facDM+offSet, minAxiY1, minAxiY2*facDM+offSet, na.rm = T),
              max(maxAxiY1, maxAxiY2*facDM+offSet, minAxiY1, minAxiY2*facDM+offSet, na.rm = T))

#Añadir el segundo eje

  if(geom=="point"){
    graf <- ggplot(data= data, aes(x= data[[x]], y= data[[y1]])) +
      geom_point(y=data[[y2]]*facDM + offSet, aes(colour= colour), alpha= alpha) +
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis( ~ (. - offSet)/facDM, name = y2), limits = vecLim)

    return(graf)
  }

  if(geom=="line"){
    graf <- ggplot(data= data, aes(x= data[[x]], y= data[[y1]])) +
      geom_line(y=data[[y2]]*facDM + offSet, aes(colour= colour), alpha= alpha) +
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis( ~ (. - offSet)/facDM, name = y2), limits = vecLim)

    return(graf)
  }

  if(geom=="pointLine"){
    graf <- ggplot(data= data, aes(x= data[[x]], y= data[[y1]])) +
      geom_line(aes(y=data[[y2]]*facDM + offSet, colour= colour), alpha= alpha) +
      geom_point(aes(y=data[[y2]]*facDM + offSet, colour= colour), alpha= alpha) +
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis( ~ (. - offSet)/facDM, name = y2), limits = vecLim)

    return(graf)
  }

  else{
    stop("geom no válido")
  }

}
```

Esta función sólo define la geometría de la representación sobre el eje secundario, por lo tanto hay que añadir posteriormente la geometría del eje principal. Adjunto un ejemplo de cómo se usa:

```
valorsx <- c(20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30)
valorsY1 <- seq(from=900, to=1000, by=1)
valorsY2 <- seq(from=0, to=100, by=1)
valorsY1 <- sample(valorsY1, size=11, replace=TRUE)
valorsY2 <- sample(valorsY2, size=11, replace=TRUE)

dades <- data.frame(varx = valorsx, vary1 = valorsY1, vary2 = valorsY2)

gplot2eix(data=dades, x=varx, y1= vary1, y2= vary2, geom= "pointLine", colour= "red", alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Con este código se genera el gráfico siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero hay un problema si se usa geom_bar() como eje principal, ya que no se pinta el gráfico de barras, es decir, el gráfico principal:

```
gplot2eix(data=dades, x=varx, y1= vary1, y2= vary2, geom= "pointLine", colour= "red", alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_bar(stat= "identity")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado varias opciones: usar geom_col(), limitar los ejes para forzar que el mínimo sea 0,... Pero nada me ha funcionado.

Agradecería si alguien supiera cómo solucionarlo, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `geom_col()` no funciona y falla silenciosamente si los valores de intervalo fijados en `scale_y_continous(limits = ...)`

1. No incluyen el 0
2. No incluyen el valor máximo de `y`

En tu código estás usando `limits = vecLimit`, que con tus datos corresponde a `c(905.000, 1036.776)`.

En https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2715 está reportado y no fue resuelto.

Va una demostración simplificada con tus datos, sin usar la función `gplot2eix()` para mantener las cosas simples.

```
ggplot(dades, aes(x = varx, y = vary1)) + geom_col() # Funciona

ggplot(dades, aes(x = varx, y = vary1)) + geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(905.000, 1036.776))  # No funciona

ggplot(dades, aes(x = varx, y = vary1)) + geom_col() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1036.776))           #Funciona
```

Si quieres prueba modificar `gplot2eix()` en el branch de `Line`, quitando el `limits=` y verás que se van a dibujar las columnas, pero en su escala natural (y, en mi opinión, correcta)

`ggplot2` hace intencionalmente difícil trabajar con dos ejes en rangos de datos diferentes. `sec_axis` esta pensado para presentar dos unidades de medida diferentes para unos mismos datos, pero no para dos series de datos con `min` y `max` muy dispares. [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right/3101876#3101876) puedes encontrar la opinión al respecto del autor de `ggplot2`.

`gplot2eix()` permite saltearse esa restricción rescatando el eje secundario, pero funciona solamente para `geoms` que no requieran un cero para ser interpretables (las barras lo requieren). Por eso no tiene problemas con puntos o línea, pero sí con barras.

Lamento no tener una solución, quizás alguien pueda aportarla.